# how would i return my object from ionic storage

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic3

i'm working on project update in which `dashboard` page is having more than `3, 000` lines of `code`.

i want to persist  the previous working

so i want to convert this function

```
  returnUserDetails(){
       var userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));

       return userDetails ;      
     }
```

**to** this one but giving `error` of `undefined` return value

```
 returnUserDetails(){
    var userData;
    this.storage.get('userData').then((val) => {
         userData = JSON.parse(val);  
     });

   return userData; 
 }
```

**Question: i cannot use global variable as this function used so many times. how can i return value correctly**

Answer (score 3):

You can just do return the promise

```
 returnUserDetails(){   
    return  this.storage.get('userData').then((val) => {
          let userData = JSON.parse(val); 
          return userData;
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with `Async` method you need to do it as shown below.

```
returnUserDetails(): Promise<any> {        
    return this.storage.get('userData').then((val) => {
         return val;  
     });      
 }
```